# Can i get into (legal) trouble, because my website looks very similar to Google News?

Tags: css, copy, google-news

I'm a student at a computer science high school, and for my first project, I decided to do a news website. Because we didn't have much time I decided not to waste much time coming up with unique designs and I took inspiration from Google News.

**I didn't copy anything from their code.** I was trying to make it as similar as possible.
Of course, my website doesn't have all features like google's, so I added a few extra features that are unique for my website.

I'm just wondering, can I be sued just for taking inspiration for the style of the website, even though it looks very similar?
The website is at the moment published.

This is a screenshot of my website (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Puthd.jpg)

Comment: Every line of code is written by me & not copied.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is has nothing to do with programming but a legal stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm NOT an attorney nor do I know any of the applicable laws in the country where you live. What follows is MY OPINION ONLY:

1. If you're not trying to sell/share/make money off your site and it's simply for an assignment. You're likely fine.
2. If you're asking that here, you're likely feeling a bit guilty. You might want to create an about section or notes in the code detailing why you copied the design and what you respect about Google's version.
3. It's likely not worth a multi-national organization's time to go after you.

All that said, for a product or production site that's intended to gain you credibility or make you money. **Copying someone else's site is always frowned upon.** Not only is it bad form, but the design (visuals & layout not just code or features) may be trademarked making it someone's legal property. Depending on your local laws, that can get you into a lot of trouble.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. 1. It's not my intent to make money nor to scam people into thinking that's a google website. 2. It's true, I feel a bit guilty for not coming up with an original design and I know its a bit cheap to do so. This was my first "big" project and I didn't want to focus too much on CSS being original. (the main objective was to make the website work). The idea about the "about" page is really good, thanks.